# Parsing HTML with Spray

Tags: scala, spray, spray-client

I get an exception `The entity “nbsp” was referenced, but not declared` when parsing valid HTML that contains the `&nbsp` entity (which makes it *invalid **XML***; I do not control the server) while unmarshalling a `HttpEntity` into a `NodeSeq` with `spray.httpx.unmarshalling.BasicUnmarshallers.NodeSeqUnmarshaller`.

I can probably preprocess the HTML to remove `&nbsp`, but what is the accepted method for parsing HTML (with `&nbsp`) with Spray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to write a [Custom Unmarshaller](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-httpx/unmarshalling/#custom-unmarshallers) that wraps [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/).